# How to use aregImpute "group" argument?

Tags: multiple-imputation, regression-strategies

Can someone provide an example of using the "group" argument with aregImpute()? I see that group=NULL is the default, but my data include a few factor variables with levels with <5 observations. My reading of the help file suggests that the "group" argument could solve this problem, and that group should be set as "a character or factor variable the same length as the number of observations in data and containing no NAs", but I don't understand how to operationalize this.

R code with errors and warnings below.

Thanks.

```
f  <- aregImpute(~gender + age + bmi + asaclass + ca199 + finalmarginstatus + grade + 
ajcctstagedistal + lvi + pni + lnpos + reoperation + adjuvantchemotherapy +    
adjuvantradiotherapy + site + race2 + preopstent + resection2 + date1 + 
date2 + survival + exclude, n.impute=nimp, x=TRUE, nk=3, tlinear=F, data=d, pr=FALSE)
```

Error in `aregImpute(~gender + age + bmi + asaclass + ca199 + finalmarginstatus +  :` 
  a bootstrap resample had too few unique values of the following variables:
`site`

In addition:

Warning messages:

1: In `aregImpute(~gender + age + bmi + asaclass + ca199:`
  `asaclass` has the following levels with < 5 observations: 1 
Consider using the group parameter to balance bootstrap samples

2: In `aregImpute(~gender + age + bmi + asaclass + ca199:`
  `finalmarginstatus` has the following levels with < 5 observations: 2 
Consider using the group parameter to balance bootstrap samples

3: In `aregImpute(~gender + age + bmi + asaclass + ca199:`
  `grade` has the following levels with < 5 observations: 4 
Consider using the group parameter to balance bootstrap samples

4: In `aregImpute(~gender + age + bmi + asaclass + ca199:`
  `ajcctstagedistal` has the following levels with < 5 observations: 0 
Consider using the group parameter to balance bootstrap samples

Comment: Questions that are only about how to use R are off topic here. It isn't clear if this is a statistical issue or a purely R issue (which is how it's presented). Can you say more about your situation, your data, your analyses & your goals here? Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with?

Comment: I have a database of 283 patients with resected cholangiocarcinomas. I am looking at the association of specific clinicopathological variables with overall and conditional survival, using Cox proportional hazards models. I am using aregImpute() to first impute missing values using predictive mean matching.